# How do I stream movies to openELEC via LAN?

Tags: openelec

I want to streammovies from my PC to the Raspberry Pi where openELEC is installed on. It works just fine. It's installed correctly. But how do I stream movies from a pc to the device? So I won't have to use any external data-storage for the movies.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your PC is Windows, and not Linux or Mac:

On your computer:

1. Put everything you want to stream into a single folder.
2. Right-click that folder in Windows Explorer / File Explorer.
3. Click Properties, then change to the Sharing tab.
4. Enable Sharing:

   - Windows 7:

     1. Click Advanced Sharing
     2. Tick the "Share this Folder" box
     3. Give the folder a name to show on the LAN (it won't change the name of the folder on the hard drive)
     4. Click OK, then OK
   - Windows XP:

     1. Tick "Share this folder on the network"
     2. Give the folder a name to show on the LAN (it won't change the name of the folder on the hard drive).
     3. Click OK

On OpenELEC:

1. Highlight the type of media you want (Video, Music, Pictures) from the home screen
2. Choose the "files" submenu item
3. Choose "Add Source" > Browse
4. Open  Windows Network (SMB), then to your computer's workgroup (the computer will probably be in either `MSHOME` or `WORKGROUP`), then to your computer
5. Choose the name you chose earlier
6. Choose OK (for Keyboard or remote, press left first)
7. Choose OK again

You can now scan that folder to the library (Right-click or press C > Scan to Library) and access it via the network.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off with Windows share (Called Samba on the OpenELEC end) but for completeness:

XBMC also is a [DLNA Client](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=UPnP/Client). You could set up a DLNA server on your PC. I don't have a Windows machine working now, but it seems to be builtin to both [Windows 7](http://www2.panasonic.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/vSupportHowToGuideDetail?storeId=15001&idval=UCM_STG_CNT_051244&catname=Blu-ray+Disc%26%238482%3B+Players&title=Usage+Guide+-++How+to+Setup+DLNA+on+Windows+7+Operating+System) and [Windows 8](http://www.topnettricks.com/windows-8-dlna-media-server/).

If you don't have either of those, or you just prefer another way of doing it, you can run [Plex](https://plex.tv/downloads) on most OSs.